# Filesystem in RAM that swaps to disk after a specified size

Tags: filesystems, ram, tmpfs

I have a process on a Linux machine that fetches some chunk of data from a host and sends it to another host. I do not control the size of the chunks I fetch, but I have a general idea of their median/average size.

I don't want to pay the cost of writing the data to the disk, as most of the time the chunks fit in RAM, so it would be a waste to write them on disk to reread them and delete them just after that.

What I would want to do is have a filesystem like tmpfs, with a limit on the in-RAM size, that swaps to disk when the limit is reached.

I tried to use a tmpfs with a lot of swap, but Linux tends to swap my programs instead of swapping the content of the tmpfs, and it deadlocks the machine.

What could I use to avoid paying the cost of disk writes for files I'm going to delete soon?

Comment: Raise `commit=` mount option.

Comment: @IporSircer ... if you are using ext3/ext4.  But it sounds like you can still get unlucky and be hit by a commit anyway, it just decreases the frequency?  Maybe XFS is better.  And if you want more than 30 seconds for any FS, you must also raise the sysctl `vm.dirty_expire_centiseconds`.

Answer (score 2):

Normal file cashing should do this for you without any extra work.
Or use the commit mount option.
Or use lvmcache.
Or use a pipe.